# Reading c# if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, delphi-xe3

Converting C#  to Pascal i stumble upon this line:

```
if (bb[1] == '1'-'0')
```

What does it mean?
If second byte is equal to string '1' minus string '0'?

Comment: `Converting C# to Pascal` - you can't do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'1'-'0'` this would give you the `1` as integer value. It is like converting character to respective integer number.

It is same as:

```
int value = (int)Char.GetNumericValue('1');
```

where `value` will hold  `1`

so your check is:

```
if(bb[1] == 1)
```

Comment: Didn't know about Char.GetNumericValue

Comment: If I am not mistaken if (bb[1]) would be sufficient.

Comment: @wittrup, no, unless `bb` is of a boolean type array, which I think it is not. in C# you can't use `if(1)` as `true`

Comment: I was thinking about in pascal, but I forgot the bool(bb[1]) anyways.  Thanks!  I got the idea of the C# statement.
I wonder why it's written like that...weird stuff...

Answer (score 0):

C# doesn't have single-quoted strings, so those are both characters (type `char`).

Values of type `char` are represented in memory as the integer value of their ASCII code, so some limited math operations work on them (like subtraction in your example).

`'1' - '0'` is the same as `(int)'1' - (int)'0'` which is `49 - 48`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: watch window in visual studio]

'1' is converted to decimal which corresponds to 49, '0' as decimal gives 48. 49 - 48 = 1. So '1' - '0' is 1 as shown in the watch window. [Here's](http://www.robelle.com/smugbook/ascii.html)  ASCII character set if you have other similar comparisons.

Comment: Yeah.  I got it, I didn't think simple enough due to the fact that the statement is completely retarded.  But that is the way it is when you read others stuff trying to write your own similar application in a language you already know.